# Querying XML data types which have xmlns node attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xml-namespaces

I have the following SQL query:

```
DECLARE @XMLDOC XML
SET @XMLDOC = '<Feed><Product><Name>Foo</Name></Product></Feed>'

SELECT  x.u.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Name
from @XMLDOC.nodes('/Feed/Product') x(u)
```

This returns:

```
Name
----
Foo
```

However, if my `<Feed>` node has an `xmlns` attribute, then this doesn't return any results:

```
DECLARE @XMLDOC XML
SET @XMLDOC = '<Feed xmlns="bar"><Product><Name>Foo</Name></Product></Feed>'

SELECT  x.u.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Name
from @XMLDOC.nodes('/Feed/Product') x(u)
```

Returns:

```
Name
----
```

This only happens if I have an `xmlns` attribute, anything else works fine.

Why is this, and how can I modify my SQL query to return results regardless of the attributes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your XML document has XML namespaces, then you need to consider those in your queries!

So if your XML looks like your sample, then you need:

```
-- define the default XML namespace to use
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'bar')
SELECT   
    x.u.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Name
from 
    @XMLDOC.nodes('/Feed/Product') x(u)
```

Or if you prefer to have explicit control over which XML namespace to use (e.g. if you have multiple), use XML namespace prefixes:

```
-- define the XML namespace 
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('bar' as b)
SELECT   
    x.u.value('b:Name[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Name
from 
    @XMLDOC.nodes('/b:Feed/b:Product') x(u)
```

Comment: +1 Is there a way of simply ignoring the xmlns? I'd tempted to convert the `XML` datatype to a string, strip out the xmlns attribute and then cast it back...

Comment: I really don't care about the namespace, and this is a third party feed with versioning on the xmlns URL, so is prone to external change

Comment: @Curt: no, when the XML namespace is there in your XML, you cannot just simply ignore it - you need to deal with it. If you only ever have one XML namespace - use approach #1 to define it as a default XML namespace and that should be fairly simple and straightforward to use

Comment: The namespace may change though. This is an external XML feed, which has versioning in the URL of the XMLNS. Is there a way of getting the XMLNS value from the XML so that I can ensure its always the same?

Comment: @Curt: I don't think there's anything built-in. You would have to textually parse the XML to find the XML namespace

Answer (score 5):

As well as the `XMLNAMESPACES` solution, you can also use the hideously bulky `local-name` syntax...

```
DECLARE @XMLDOC XML
SET @XMLDOC = '<Feed xmlns="bar"><Product><Name>Foo</Name></Product></Feed>'

SELECT  x.u.value('*[local-name() = "Name"][1]', 'varchar(100)') as Name
from @XMLDOC.nodes('/*[local-name() = "Feed"]/*[local-name() = "Product"]') x(u)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the alternative solution. Apart from being hideous, is this heavy on performance?

Comment: I would imagine so! It does have advantage (or possibly disadvantage? :)) of not actually caring about the namespace unlike the `XMLNAMESPACES` solution which specifically targets a given namespace.

Comment: Further to this - I find XML parsing in SQLServer to be pretty damn slow regardless... Maybe I do it wrong!

Comment: Thanks, as this solution is most probably not best practice, I've not marked it as answer, but will refer to it in desperate times of need! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can [define namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx) like:

```
WITH    XMLNAMESPACES ('bar' as b)
SELECT  x.u.value('b:Name[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Name
FROM    @XMLDOC.nodes('/b:Feed/b:Product') x(u)
```