# Can't seem to query xml data type correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I want to successfully query (in SSMS) a column in my database which contains different types of so called AddressElements in XML. The table which contains all AddressElements looks as follows:

```
create table AddressElements(Address.Id int, AddressType.Id int, AddressElement xml)
```

A sample of the XML in the AddressElement xml-column is structured as follows:

```
<AddressElements xmlns="http://www.myorganisation.nl/schemas/2007/BusinessPropertySchema/AddressElements/Postadres">
    <Postadres_default Straatnaam="Main Street" Huisnummer="1" Postcode="9999 XX" Plaats="ROTTERDAM" />
</AddressElements>
```

I started by trying the following query with a WHERE-statement for filtering out the specific AddressElement I'm interested in.

```
SELECT m.c.value('@Straatnaam', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Straatnaam
, m.c.value('@Huisnummer', 'int') AS Huisnummer
, m.c.value('@Postcode', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Postcode
, m.c.value('@Plaats', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Plaats

FROM Address as s
    outer apply s.AddressElements.nodes('AddressElements/Postadres_default') AS m(c)

WHERE s.AddressTypeId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002'
```

Unfortunatelly the result is:

```
Straatnaam  Huisnummer  Postcode    Plaats
NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
```

I've searched for problems/posts similar to mine but so far I couldn't make those solutions work for my case. It would be great if any of you can help me out! Thank you very much in advance!

Kind regards, Ingmar

Comment: This is an issue with the fact you have a namespace in the `AddressElements` node. One quick way of fixing this would be to change the nodes part to `('/*:AddressElements/*:Postadres_default')`

Comment: @ZLK Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I still got the same result. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I just ran a test with the sample you provided and that seems to work, but if it's still not working for you, I'd suggest looking around at different questions that address using name spaces when querying XML. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461834/querying-xml-data-types-which-have-xmlns-node-attributes

Comment: @I.deSwart XPath suggested by ZLK should have worked, I think. Consider creating a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to demonstrate the problem (see: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2998271))

Comment: I finally made it work! Somehow when I tried it last night I mixed up the attributes of two address types, that's why it didn't work. Probably too tired to think straight! Thank you very much @ZLK!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions provided in the comments by ZLK should work.

For example, try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Address (AddressId int, AddressTypeId uniqueidentifier, AddressElements xml)

INSERT INTO dbo.Address (AddressId, AddressTypeId, AddressElements)
VALUES (1,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002',
'<AddressElements xmlns="http://www.myorganisation.nl/schemas/2007/BusinessPropertySchema/AddressElements/Postadres">
    <Postadres_default Straatnaam="Main Street" Huisnummer="1" Postcode="9999 XX" Plaats="ROTTERDAM" />
</AddressElements>')

SELECT m.c.value('@Straatnaam', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Straatnaam
, m.c.value('@Huisnummer', 'int') AS Huisnummer
, m.c.value('@Postcode', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Postcode
, m.c.value('@Plaats', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Plaats
FROM Address as s
    outer apply s.AddressElements.nodes('*:AddressElements/*:Postadres_default') AS m(c)
WHERE s.AddressTypeId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.myorganisation.nl/schemas/2007/BusinessPropertySchema/AddressElements/Postadres' as s)
SELECT m.c.value('@Straatnaam', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Straatnaam
, m.c.value('@Huisnummer', 'int') AS Huisnummer
, m.c.value('@Postcode', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Postcode
, m.c.value('@Plaats', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Plaats
FROM Address as s
    outer apply s.AddressElements.nodes('s:AddressElements/s:Postadres_default') AS m(c)
WHERE s.AddressTypeId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I finally made it work!